# How to save memory used in subviews as my iOS app enters the background after the App snapshot has been taken

Tags: ios, memory, background-process

I see a lot of posts about people trying to obscure sensitive information from their app snapshot so that its not readable in the multitasking app selector. But I have a different problem.

I'm trying to save as much memory in my app as possible when it enters the background, and one of my app's views has a lot of subviews that is the largest memory usage of my entire app. I've written code to remove and delete these subviews, which i then recreate when the app returns to the foreground (I've actually called these methods in the resign active and did become active methods). Everything is working fine but when I delete these subviews, the view correctly appears rather empty, just in time for the system app snapshot to be taken. So as the app is restored this empty view is displayed for a short time before the app renders properly.

I'd like to be able to manage these views but I guess it needs to happen AFTER the app snapshot has taken place.

Actually profiling the app's memory usage I've noticed that the large (70meg) memory usage that's present whilst the app is in the foreground drawing these views drops right down when the app is backgrounded even if i don't manually delete the views myself. The documentation is clear that the actual backing CA layers etc are all handled by the system so thankfully the majority of memory savings are already being made by the system itself. But still there's another 5-10meg that I can save by doing what I've described here so it feels like a good idea. Is it possible though?

I wonder if I should request to be left running a little longer which I think i saw was possible may be the solution? Especially if the app snapshot is taken before this extra time is given to the app.. This would mean the screenshot is correct and the memory is saved a split second later.

Thanks for your time, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're worried about 5-10 megs of RAM. The system will reclaim lots of memory by blowing away the backing layers, as you said, and recreating them when the app is foregrounded again. But what, exactly, do you hope to accomplish by reclaiming more memory yourself?

Unfortunately you can't control when the snapshot is taken. You could, I suppose, do a dispatch_after to have your view destruction code happen after a delay, but this wouldn't be deterministic since you don't know when the snapshot will be taken. And it's also possible that the code won't be run at all if your app is asleep when the dispatch timer goes.

I think you may be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was trying to follow the documentation which advised removing anything that can be removed and saving as much memory as possible whenever your app goes into the background. Tbh now that I can see how much the memory is getting reduced by on the device I'm not too concerned with leaving the views intact.

Comment: I guess my concern was that 5-10meg could be enough to make my app more likely to be terminated first as the system gets loaded. Not that it matters either way really. As I said was just trying to do what apple told me to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a snapshot view on top of your view hierarchy before removing the subviews.

```
UIView *snapshotView = [view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

Not exactly sure that will help save much of those few MBs you worry about, but that's the common way of doing something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll take a look at the method, I presume this would let me cover up any changes that will happen when I manipulate the sub views? If I can't solve it I'm happy to leave my views in place now I know that so much memory has already been saved by the system

Comment: This method looks great. Maybe I can use it in other places to hide core data loads taking a second or so to happen, showing tables emptying until their data reloads. Thanks a lot!!